# Don't echo the same parent category name inside loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, unique

I have some code, which show me:

-- Parent custom category name

--- Child custom category name

---- Custom post name

There are this code:

```
    <?php
    $post_type = 'zakony';
    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );
     
    foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :
        $arg = array('hierarchical'  => false, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'DESC');
        $terms = get_terms("all", $arg);
    
        foreach( $terms as $term ) :

           if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) :
           $term = array_pop( $terms );
           $parent_term = ( $term->parent ? get_term( $term->parent, 'all' ) : $term );
           echo '<strong>'.$parent_term->name.'</strong><br>';      
           endif; ?>
          <strong class="child_cat"><?php echo $term->name; ?></strong>
        <?php
        $args = array(MY ARGS GOES HERE);
        $posts = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="child_url"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach;
endforeach; ?>
```

And its work fine and looks like:
[click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vzg9.png)

But how I can show the parent custom category name only once if its same?
I mean, i`d like to show the unique parent custom category name, and dont show it more than once if it same! Could you help me please?

Comment: Just order by parent category name and create a variable which holds the last in parent name in the loop (if ($lastparentname === parent_term->name) -> do not echo

Comment: **Rienk**, thank you, but this is not a solution! I need this order what I have there, it's ok for me! Also there are no needs to find the last in parent name in the loop, BUT I need to find and echo only unique parent_term->name in the loop... [look here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i23dlitvxoy481z/scrn.png) there are two same parent cat name (red arrow) and two same (blue arrow). And I want to show only once parent cat name (red\blue arrow) and don't show it again if it is same.

Comment: This one works well                                                                                                             `$org = array('1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '5', '6'); 
    $new = array_unique($org);        
    var_dump($org); ` works well and show only unique! But how to put all **parent_term->name** into $org array now?

Comment: I found a solution:        `if ($parent_term->name !=$_parent_term) echo '<strong>'.$parent_term->name.'</strong><br>';
$_parent_term = $parent_term->name;`